# For every normed algebra $\mathbb K$ with $\dim(A)\lt\infty$, prove that $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ continuous on the set of all inverse of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $(A,+,.,\times)$ a normed algebra over $\mathbb K$ with $\dim(A)\lt\infty$, $N$ the norm and  $B$ the set of all inverse of $(A,\times)$ and $\varphi : B\to B$ such that $x\mapsto x^{-1}$.

Prove that $\varphi\in C^0(B,B)$

My proof :

---

Let $x\in B$. We want : $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta>0,\forall y\in B, N(x-y)<\delta \implies N(\varphi(x)-\varphi(y))<\varepsilon$.

- Searching for $\delta$ :

$N(x^{-1}-y^{-1})=N(y^{-1}(y-x)x^{-1})\le N(y^{-1})N(x^{-1})N(y-x)\le N(y^{-1})N(x^{-1})\delta$

Let $z=x-y$ so $y^{-1}=(x-z)^{-1}=x^{-1}(e-zx^{-1})^{-1}$.

- Suppose that $\underline {N(z)<1/N(x^{-1})}, (\text{so }\underline {\delta \le 1/2N(x^{-1})}\text{ works})$ and prove that : $\bbox[yellow] {(e-zx^{-1})^{-1}\le 1/(1-\delta N(x^{-1}))}$

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (zx^{-1})^k$ so $(e-zx^{-1})S_n = S_n -S_{n+1}+e=e-(zx^{-1})^{n+1}$.

$N(e-(zx^{-1})^{n+1}-e)=N((zx^{-1})^{n+1})\le (N(zx^{-1}))^{n+1}$ but $N(zx^{-1})<1$ so $(e-zx^{-1})S_n \to e$.

It can be proven that $S_n(e-zx^{-1})\to e$ and $S_\infty = (e-zx^{-1})^{-1}$.

Also, $\forall n\in\mathbb N, N(S_n)\le\sum_{k=0}^n N(zx^{-1})^k\le\dfrac{1}{1-N(zx^{-1})}$ so $N(S_\infty)\le\dfrac{1}{1-N(zx^{-1})}$

And, $N(zx^{-1})\le N(z)N(x^{-1})\le\delta N(x^{-1})$ so $\dfrac{1}{1-N(zx^{-1})}\le\dfrac{1}{1-\delta N(x^{-1})}$

$$\bbox[yellow] {(e-zx^{-1})^{-1}\le \dfrac{1}{1-\delta N(x^{-1})}}$$

That implies $N(y^{-1})\le \dfrac{N(x^{-1})}{1-\delta N(x^{-1})}$. So I choose :

$$N(x^{-1}-y^{-1})\le \dfrac{N(x^{-1})^2\delta}{1-\delta N(x^{-1})}=\varepsilon/2$$

I find : $$\delta = \min\left(\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2N(x^{-1})^2+\varepsilon N(x^{-1})}, \dfrac{1}{2N(x^{-1})}\right)$$

I found $\delta$ such that $\forall y\in B, N(x-y)<\delta \implies N(\varphi(x)-\varphi(y))<\varepsilon$

So $\varphi\in C^0(B,B)$.

---

I want to know if my prove is right and if there is a quicker way to prove it.

Comment: I don’t follow your proof since $(x-z)^{-1} = ((e-zx^{-1})x)^{-1} = x^{-1} (e-zx^{-1})^{-1}$.

Comment: I'll edit it. Changing into $x^{-1}(e-zx^{-1})^{-1}$, will change $\delta$ but my prove doesn't change a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^\times$ is non-empty means that $A$ is unital.

If   $1-z\in A^\times$ then $$\forall n,\qquad (1-z)^{-1}=(1-z^{n+1}+z^{n+1})(1-z)^{-1}= \sum_{k=0}^n z^k + z^{n+1}(1-z)^{-1}$$
from which for $\|z\|\le 1/2$ $$\|(1-z)^{-1}-1\| = \lim_{n\to \infty} \|\sum_{k=0}^n z^k + z^{n+1}(1-z)^{-1}-1\|$$ $$\le \limsup_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \|z\|^k + \|z\|^{n+1}\|(1-z)^{-1}\|= \frac{\|z\|}{1-\|z\|}$$
And hence for $x\in A^\times$ and $\|x^{-1}\|\|z\|\le 1/2$
$$\|(x-z)^{-1}-x^{-1}\|\le \|x^{-1}\| \|(1-x^{-1}z)^{-1}-1\|\le \|x^{-1}\|\frac{\|x^{-1}\|\|z\| }{1-\|x^{-1}\|\|z\|}$$
which proves that the inverse is norm-continuous at $x$.